# Execute txt file into an exe file to be executed by a windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

The title is a bit confusing, so I'll explain better here.
I need to open an exe file with some launch options contained in the txt file,
the most simple solution is to drag the txt file above the exe, and it'll launch.
My question is, is there a method to do this by a batch file?

What i did without success:

```
START program.exe
START launchoptions.txt
...(Things that aren't influencing)
```

Comment: Which program you're talking about? If it's something like notepad you can pass files as arguments.

Comment: if dragging a txt file is working, it should also work to give it as parameter: `program.exe launchoptions.txt`. `start` shouldn't be necessary with .exe files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the most simple solution is to drag the txt file above the exe, and
>   it'll launch

When you drag-drop a file onto an application in Explorer it does nothing more than to pass the file name as argument to the program, therefore your solution is simply:

```
START program.exe launchoptions.txt
...(Things that aren't influencing)
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped